# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I upgraded the angular(2.1.2)and angular-cli version to latest, and I get the following error for each component I have:

```
ERROR in ./src/app/members/view-news/view-news.component.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'view-news.component.css' in 'c:\xampp\htdocs\myapp\src\app\members\view-news'
 @ ./src/app/members/view-news/view-news.component.ts 74:21-55
 @ ./src/app/app.module.ts
 @ ./src/app/index.ts
 @ ./src/main.ts
 @ multi main
```

Although the file `view-news.component.css` exists in the same folder of the `view-news.component.ts` and worked in previous version. What's wrong?

Answer (score 6):

did you try `./view-news.component.css` as path?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you change the comments tag from `<dom-element>` to 'test.html' if you have it surrounding with `test.html` it will fail.

Answer (score 0):

here is my Solution

In my case

path is like this "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",

i have corrected it by

**"./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",**

Actual Code

```
"styles": [
          "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        ],
        "scripts": [
          "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
          "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        ],
```